# html button click to add value in javascript class

Tags: javascript, local-storage, shopping-cart, buttonclick, domcontentloaded

I have a few buttons with different categories. When the user clicks on the button, the correct category should be displayed. In every category, there are a few products, each with their own "add to cart"-button.
So, the user clicks "beds" and then adds item #3 to the cart (which updates and so on).

I have managed to do this with classes IF the user can't choose a category. It also works without classes if I add the buttons dynamically in js. But again, without allowing the user to choose a category.

I also want the user to be able to search for an item, get the item/ items displayed, and add it to the cart.

Get Products

```
class Products {
  async getProducts() {
    try {
      const result = await fetch("/data/products.json");
      const data = await result.json();
      let products = data.items;
      products = products.map((item) => {
        const { category, title, price } = item;
        const { id } = item.sys;
        const image = item.image.url;
        return { category, title, price, id, image };
      });
      return products;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Display Products

```
class UI {   
  async displayProducts(products, searchText) { 
    let matches = products.filter(item => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`,'gi');
      return item.category.match(regex);
    })  
     
    let result = "";
    matches.forEach((product) => {
      result += `
         <!-- single product  -->
        <article class="product">
          <div class="img-container">
            <img
              src=${product.image}
              alt="product"
              class="product-img"
            />
            <button class="bag-btn" data-id=${product.id}>
              <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">add to cart</i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <h3>${product.title}</h3>
          <h4>$${product.price}</h4>
        </article>     
         <!-- end single product -->
        `;
    });    
    productDOM.innerHTML = result;
  }
  
  getBagButtons() {
    const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".bag-btn")];
```

In HTML I used onclick="displayProducts('bed')"

This will not work tho, since displayProducts is in a class.

I have also tried to add an id to each button and add an eventlistener in DOMContentLoaded, but that wrecks the rest of my DOMContentLoaded stuff

DOMContentLoaded

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const ui = new UI();
  const products = new Products();

  // setup app
  ui.setupAPP();
  
  products
    .getProducts()
    .then((products) => {  
         
      ui.displayProducts(products);
      Storage.saveProducts(products);
    })
    .then(() => {
      ui.getBagButtons(); 
      ui.cartLogic();
    });
});
```

These are just a few of the things I've tried, but for each try, one issue is fixed but one or more issues are added, so I could really use some help here. Thanks!

Comment: You have access to the instance of the UI class that is initialized... all you need to do is say `onclick="ui.displayProducts('bed')"`;

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that with no success.  <li class="categoryButton"><a href="#" onclick="ui.displayProducts('bed')">beds</a></li> results in errormessage: Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM31577 index.html:30). I also thought that would be the way.

Comment: when you go to your console and type `console.log(ui);`, does it return a defined ui object?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: Did you write these classes?

Comment: Haha, yeah. I got some help, but then it didn't work, so I've been changing things like a thousand times. I'm also trying a version without, or with less classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224760/discussion-between-battleaxe-and-shanerm13).

Comment: So... I think the reason why the onclick doesn't work is because ui isn't defined... as does the console... My recommendation is to define a variable outside of the event listener called something to the effect of `var uiCP;`. Inside your event listener... at the very bottom say uiCP = `{...ui};`... then you can use onclick=uiCP.displayProducts('bed'); Thats probably the easiest fix...

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes we made:

All category buttons gets this event listener

```
onclick="searchNdisplay(new UI, new Products, 'category text');"
```

This initializes the ui and products and they get displayed, so we changed it to use the searchNdisplay function

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const ui = new UI();
const products = new Products();

// setup app
ui.setupAPP();

searchNdisplay(ui, products, "");

Storage.saveProducts(products);
});
```

This function repopulates the page with products that met the search criteria.

```
function searchNdisplay(ui, products, search)
{

    products
        .getProducts()
        .then((products) => {

    if (search == "")
    {
        ui.displayProducts(products);
    }
    else
    {
        ui.displayProducts(products, search);
    }
})
    .then(() => {
        ui.getBagButtons();
        ui.cartLogic();
    });
}
```